# using dropdown to populate sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I know how to set parameters to textboxes but I'm not sure how to do it with dropdown lists ? Here is what I tried but it didn't work.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eadd", txt_eadd.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txt_title.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txt_fname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", txt_sname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txt_dob.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", counrty.DropDownList);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@distilry", distilry.DropDownList);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txt_add.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add2", txt_add2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add3", txt_add3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add4", txt_add4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", txt_post.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mob", txt_mob.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fav", txt_fav.Text);
```

Comment: `counrty.DropDownList.SelectedValue` or `counrty.DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need the selected value or the selected index, whichever you're searching on - so:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", counrty.SelectedValue);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", counrty.SelectedIndex);
```